# ASP.NET MVC: Would it be good practice to have an API Controller action return both View and/or JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, view

I am programming an API that would be used by both a web app and a mobile app and I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 in my technology stack.

Currently, I have an Rest-like API service which returns data in JSON format.
This works well for the mobile app, but I also want to make it work for the web app as well.

Would having the controller action return either a HTML View or JsonResult be a good approach for this?

The only difference between the web app and the mobile app is the view layer; the app logic is the same.

I guess I could create a controller that is used for the web app, but I think the a lot of logic would be duplicated from the API controller.

**Edit**

I do have another layer that handles all the app logic, but the API controller still has some logic to validate the parameters and error handling when it returns the JSON response. The duplicate logic so far would be the validation part.

Here is some code snippets:

```
public JsonResult GetList(string accessToken, string listId)
 {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        return Json(new { success = false, exceptionMessage = "Facebook access token is required." });
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(listId))
        return Json(new { success = false, exceptionMessage = "The list id is required." });

    string facebookId = null;
    var facebookIdParseSuccess = GetFacebookId(accessToken, out facebookId);

    if (!facebookIdParseSuccess)
        return Json(new { success = false, exceptionMessage = "There was a problem accessing your Facebook profile information." });

    try
    {
        _groceryListManager.FacebookId = facebookId;
        var groceryList = _groceryListManager.GetList(listId);
        GroceryListViewModel mappedList = new GroceryListViewModel();
        Mapper.Map(groceryList, mappedList);
        return Json(new { success = true, results = mappedList });

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, exceptionMessage = "..."});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen one action method return both before, but, in my opinion, you are better off having two separate action methods. You can have them both call off to another method with the shared code, but since they are used for two very different things, you might find it is easier to maintain if you have two methods (a future requirement might cause one to change in a way that makes it difficult to support both in a single method).

Whether they are in the same controller or not is really more dependent on the nature, size, and complexity of the application. I have separated the API as a completely different project from the HTML. I have shared dlls for accessing the data and other common functions, but the MVC projects are different.

Comment: Thanks! After reviewing the list of API calls, only a few required a Html view, and I think it would be simpler to just have a separate controller for the website portion of the app. I can still call the API actions via AJAX and the API controller also is used by mobile and possible flash clients.

Answer (score 2):

If your view's model is suitable for returning as JSON too, doing both in the same action can work well.  Something like:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
  FooModel model = new FooModel();

  // Code here to build the model

  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    return Json(model);
  else
    return View(model);
}
```

This also helps guide you into the pit of success in terms of using progressive enhancement.  If the URL for HTML and JSON is the same, it's that much easier to use accessible/SEO-friendly URLs in your markup and then progressively enhance by adding unobtrusive event handlers to replace that with requests for the JSON in JavaScript-enabled browsers.

Comment: That sounds like a good approach! Would the value for IsAjaxRequest be determined by one of the post variables?

Comment: It's determined by testing for the semi-standard convention of setting an `X-Requested-With` HTTP header with the value `XMLHttpRequest`, which some AJAX libraries automatically set on their aync requests.  Those libraries include MicrosoftAjax.js and jQuery, so most of us using ASP.NET MVC are covered.  If you're using something else or rolling your requests by hand, you can still set that HTTP header manually and it will be correctly reflected by `Request.IsAjaxRequest()`.

Comment: I would have to do my homework on this, but when the mobile apps calls the API, then Request.IsAjaxRequest() would have to be true as well. Either way, I am sure I program it so that the mobile apps do set the X-Requested-With to XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you exactly want to achieve:

- Create a ViewEngine which returns the correct View
  example: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx
- alternatively you can return a View or JSON depending on a parameter in the URL

Answer (score 0):

> but I think the a lot of logic would
>   be duplicated from the API controller.

I think you answered the question yourself. I would keep them in the same controller. :)